# I want to clean my list in Python but I don't know how to do

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search/?specials=1"

response = requests.get(url)

icerik = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(icerik,"html.parser")

hepsi = list()


for i in (soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"responsive_search_name_combined"})):
    hepsi.append(i.text)

print(hepsi)
```

Hello, I wrote a code like above. Hovewer, the result that I want is not like this. When I print "hepsi" list, I see there are many "\n" in my list but I don't want to them in my list. I just want to have the names. **How can I clean my list from unnecessary "\n" elemans?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's more going on in these strings with the whitespace than a simple `.strip()` can handle. We can replace all the internal whitespace (which includes newlines) with one space.. so each run of whitespace will be a single space, and we can strip off the whitespace at the beginning and end of the strings as well.

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> hepsi = [re.sub(r"\s+", " ", x).strip() for x in hepsi]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.strip()` to remove the \n. That yields empty strings.
Remove them from your list with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
hepsi = [x for x in hepsi if x.strip() != '']
```